# ANSI C Dynamic Memory Allocation and when exactly we should free the memory

Tags: c, malloc, free, ansi-c

I am trying to get my head around memory allocations and freeing them in ANSI C. The problem is I don't know when to free them.

1) Does program exit free the allocated memory itself (even if I didn't do it by `free()`)?

2) Let's say my code is something like this: (please don't worry about the full code of those structs at the moment. I am after the logic only)

```
snode = (stock_node *) realloc(snode, count * sizeof(stock_node));
struct stock_list slist = { snode, count };
stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = (stock_list_ptr) malloc(sizeof(stock_list_ptr));
slist_ptr = &slist;
tm->stock = slist_ptr;
```

So above; snode goes to stock_list and stock_list goes to slist pointer and it goes to tm->stock.

Now, as I have assigned all of them to tm->stock at the end, do I have to free snode and slist_ptr? Because tm struct will be used in rest of the program. If I free snode and slist_ptr will tm struct lose the values?

Comment: This line leaks your alloc just above it: 'slist_ptr = &slist;' Probably not what you intended to do.

Comment: Think of it this way: For each malloc you do, you need to do a corresponding free. In a perfect program, the number of frees will equal the number of mallocs.

Comment: @CharlieBurns thanks for your comment. What would be the right way then? to fix the `slist_ptr = &slist;`

Comment: calling exit() or dropping out of main, ends the program and all the resources, including the mallocs, are released.

Comment: It's hard to comment on 'the right way' because it's not obvious ( to me anyway ) what you are trying to do.

Comment: this is my assignment. that's why I am a bit hesitant to post the full code. I don't want to be in trouble with uni. However, last few days I couldn't even finish the just 1 function because of strange problem. Imagine this: I put a basic `printf` at the beginning of the function to print the value of tm->stock element. All good. I get the correct value. Then I add exact copy the `printf` somewhere in the middle of the same function. First print gives the right value and second doesn't. Although I don't even change its value. How come it is possible? I don't do anything with it.

Comment: Well, post the code for that one function. It's easy trounce all over memory with C and mallocs. Or, you can put the print statement after every line and you'll find the line that messed it up.

Comment: Note that `snode = (stock_node *) realloc(snode, count * sizeof(stock_node));` is a recipe for trouble. If the reallocation fails, you have written a null pointer over `snode`, so you've no way to release the space that `snode` used to point at. Any `realloc()` of the form `var = realloc(var, size);` is extremely suspect. You should use `stock_node *new_snode = realloc(snode, count * sizeof(*snode));` or thereabouts, then test whether `new_snode` is 0 or NULL, and handle the situation if it is not. The same applies to every memory allocation; you should always check that the allocation worked.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually Ido check the allocation with `if (snode == NULL) { abort(); } `

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, when the program exits, the process exits, and the OS reclaims the stack and heap space allocated to that process. Imagine how bad it would be if the OS could not take back unallocated memory from crashed processes!
2. As a general rule of thumb, for every `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or — with caveats — `realloc()`) in a program, there should be a corresponding `free()`. So in short you need to *at some point* free both the space associated with `snode` and the space associated with `slist_ptr`.

In this particular instance, you've actually managed to create for yourself a memory leak. When you do the `malloc()` for `slist_ptr`, you allocated 4 bytes (8 bytes on 64-bit) for that pointer. On the next line, you reassign `slist_ptr` to point to the location of `slist`, which means you no longer have a pointer to the space you allocated for `slist_ptr`.

If you did call free on `tm->stock`, you would thus free the space associated with the initial `realloc` (be sure you mean `realloc` and not `malloc`), but you still are leaking due to the `malloc` for `slist_ptr`.

Comment: Thanks themaestro. Charlie mentined the same about the leak. How should I fix it? Also I am trying to understand that once snode assigned to slist is it safe to free? Remember that slist will be continued to used within the program until exit. If I free the snode, will I lose the values of snode or I won't lose anything because all assigned to slist?

Comment: In order to fix the leak, it *seems to me* like you should not malloc when you create slist_ptr, rather, just assign it directly to slist. Though I second Charlie, it's not entirely clear what your'e going for.

Comment: And once you slist is set equal to snode, if you free *that location in memory*, you lose its contents permanently. You should only free when you are done using what you want to use.

Comment: And as a side note, when you think about dynamic memory, try not to get hung up on the individual pointers, but rather think in terms of *where they are pointing to in memory*, as if memory was just a giant linear space with a bunch of location labels on it. Many pointers can refer to the same place, but the place they point to is unique, so to speak.

Comment: when you say "you should not malloc when you create slist_ptr, rather, just assign it directly to slist." would this be correct to use: `stock_list_ptr slist_ptr = slist;`